# How do I access SQLite DB in an activity, from inside a fragment using Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I created an SQLite database with a table and entries in `MainActivity.kt`. I have a fragment `AllUsersFragment.kt` with a list on it. Whenever an item on the list is clicked, the fragment should run a query to get/edit something from the database in `MainActivity.kt`.

I tried to create a function in `MainActivity.kt` which could be called from the fragment, but it turns out that the database is not even accessible outside the `onCreate()` of `MainActivity.kt`. I am using Kotlin language.
I found answers here for Java, but none for Kotlin.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        try {
            val myDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("CreditsDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null)

//            myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS credits (serial INT(3) PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(256), credits INT(10))")

//            myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO credits (serial, name, credits) VALUES (1, 'Andrew Jackson', 10000)")
//            myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO credits (serial, name, credits) VALUES (2, 'Barry Alan', 20000)")
//            myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO credits (serial, name, credits) VALUES (3, 'Caitlyn Snow', 15000)")
//            myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO credits (serial, name, credits) VALUES (4, 'Drake Ramoray', 8000)")

        }
        catch(e: Exception)
        {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    //Initial Fragment during app start
        title = resources.getString(R.string.allusers)
        loadFragment(AllUsersFragment())

    //BOTTOM NAVIGATION BAR
        navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.navigation_allusers -> {
                    title = resources.getString(R.string.allusers)
                    loadFragment(AllUsersFragment())
                    return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }

                R.id.navigation_transfer -> {
                //Omitted unimportant code here
                }

                R.id.navigation_logs -> {
                //Omitted unimportant code here     
                }

            }

            false
        }
    }


    fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

AllUsersFragment.kt

```
class AllUsersFragment : Fragment(){

    private lateinit var listView:ListView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_allusers, container, false)
        val details = UserDetailsFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()

        listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList)

        val userNames = arrayOf(
            "Andrew Jackson",
            "Barry Alan",
            "Caitlyn Snow",
            "Drake Ramoray",
        )

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userNames)
        listView.adapter = adapter

        listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->

            val userName = userNames[i]
            bundle.putString("str", userName)
            bundle.putInt("int", i)
            details.arguments = bundle
//=========================================================

        //expected operation here:
        //var query = "SELECT credits (column name) FROM credits (table name) WHERE serial = (id+1)"
        //var creditsAmt : Int = myDatabase.execSQL(query)  (SOMEHOW THIS SHOULD ACCESS DATABASE IN MainActivity.kt)

//=========================================================
            val transaction = fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, details)
            transaction.addToBackStack(null)
            transaction.commit()


        }

        return rootView
    }
}
```

Please find the commented section in `AllUsersFragment.kt` above which describes what I exactly need.

Comment: Make a public method in Activity and then call it from the fragment with query string as `(activity as MainActivity).yourMethod(query)`. The `myDatabase.execSQL(query)` can be executed in the public method written in the activity. And it should return the required value which can be used in fragment.

Comment: @Antonio As far as I knew, there are no methods in Kotlin, right? And I tried creating a function but it wouldn't show access to ```myDatabase``` outside the ```onCreate``` function.

Comment: declare myDatabase as global in activity

Comment: Consider using [Google's ORM called Room](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-persistence/#2) to get a better structure over your database access

Answer (score 0):

you do it like this :

```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        val myDatabase : YourDatabaseClassName? = null

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            try {
                myDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("CreditsDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null)


            }
            catch(e: Exception)
            {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
```

and inside your fragment you can use your database instance like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_allusers, container, false)

   .......

   // here how you call your database instance
    var query = "SELECT credits (column name) FROM credits (table name) WHERE serial = (id+1)"
    var creditsAmt : Int = (activity as MainActivity).myDatabase!!.execSQL(query)

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the ```YourDatabaseClassName``` part. Do I have to create this class under the function I have (outside the ```onCreate()```)? And if I'm using ```myDatabase!!.execSQL(query)``` in the fragment file, why do I need a class with a different name?